# Viewpager which is inside scrollview scrolls to the top when redirecting the page

Tags: android

I have a scrollview which has some view along with the view pager in its bottom ,which has grid view inside it. when moved to the next activity and resumed to the activity the viewpager which is in the bottom scrolls to the top.

I have no idea to redirect the scrollview page with viewpager without changing its scroll position.Any suggestion??

Comment: user request focus

Comment: myself got the answer just add "  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the layout which scrollview is enclosing

Comment: @ramya works but blocks nested scroll functionality :(